# Extending point-wise bound to uniform bound

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Suppose $f(t,x)\in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^n)$. Further suppose that for each $t$
$$ C(t):= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} |f(t,x)|<\infty \, .$$

Does it follow that $f$ is bounded?

Note that $C(t)$ need not be continuous as is evidenced by $f(t,x)= \sin(t x)$.

Comment: If $\mathcal C_0$ stands for continuous functions that vanish at infinity, they are all bounded even without further assumptions. If not, you need to clarify the notation.

Comment: That was a typo. It has been fixed.

Comment: To be explicit, what I mean is that $f$ is jointly continuous in $t$ and $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. Start from any non-zero continuous function $\phi$ with compact support in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and define

$f(t,x)=\phi(tx)/t$ for $t>0$ and $f(0,x)=0$.

Comment: Note that the continuous dependence from $x$ is neither sufficient nor necessary for the positive answer to hold. If $\{f(\cdot, x)\}_x$ is an equicontinuous family of functions on $[0,1]$, then either $C(t)=\infty$ for all $t$ or $C$ is a continuous real valued function of $t$ (thus bounded).